# Return string pattern match plus text before and after pattern

Tags: r

Suppose I have diary entries from 5 people and I want to determine if they mention any food-related key words. I want an output of the key word with a window of one word before and after to provide context before determining if they are food-related.

The search should be case-insensitive, and it's ok if the key word is embedded in another word. E.g., If a key word is "rice", I want to output to include "price".

Assume I have the following data:

```
foods <- c('corn', 'hot dog', 'ham', 'rice')
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                 diary = c('I ate rice and corn today',
                            'Sue ate my corn.',
                            'He just hammed it up',
                            'Corny jokes are my fave',
                            'What is the price of milk'))
```

The output I'm looking for is:

```
|ID|Output                          |
|--|--------------------------------|
|1 |"ate rice and", "and corn today"|
|2 |"my corn"                       |
|3 |"just hammed it"                |
|4 |"Corny jokes"                   |
|5 |"the price of"                  |
```

I've used `strings::stri_detect` but the output includes the entire diary entry.

I've used `strings::stri_extract` but I can't find a way to include one word before and after the key word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution works when the same food appears ***multiple*** times in the same phrase. It is based on the splitting of each phrase into its individual words.

```
library(tidyverse)

extract3 <- function(txt, word)
{
  str_split(txt, "\\W") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    {. ->> w} %>% 
    map(~ str_extract(.x,regex(paste0("(.)*",word,"(.)*"),ignore_case=T))) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    is.na() %>% 
    `!` %>% 
    which() %>% 
    map_chr(~ paste(
      w[unique(c(max(c(.x-1,1)),.x,min(c(.x+1,length(w)))))], collapse = " ")) %>% 
    paste(collapse = ", ")
}

df_out <- tibble()
for (i in 1:nrow(df))
  for (j in 1:length(foods))
    df_out <- rbind(df_out,
          tibble(
            id=df$id[i],diary=df$diary[i], output=extract3(df$diary[i],foods[j])))

df_out %>% 
  filter(output != "") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(output=paste(output,collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()
```

**EDITED (WITHOUT FOR CYCLES)**

```
library(tidyverse)
extract3 <- function(txt, word)
{
  str_split(txt, "\\W") %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    {. ->> w} %>% 
    map(~ str_extract(.x,regex(paste0("(.)*",word,"(.)*"),ignore_case=T))) %>% 
    unlist() %>% 
    is.na() %>% 
    `!` %>% 
    which() %>% 
    map_chr(~ paste(
      w[unique(c(max(c(.x-1,1)),.x,min(c(.x+1,length(w)))))], collapse = " ")) %>% 
    paste(collapse = ", ") %>% 
    str_trim()
}

map_dfr(
  1:nrow(df), 
  function(id) map_dfr(1:length(foods), ~ tibble(
            id = df$id[id],
            diary = df$diary[id],
            output = extract3(df$diary[id], foods[.])))) %>% 
  filter(output != "") %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(output = paste(output,collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution. The output is is exhaustive (good) but it's the same for all IDs. Is it possible for the output to be limited to the relevant IDs?

Comment: I do not quite understand your comment: the output of my code matches exactly what you gave as the output of your example (in your initial post).

Comment: Or do you just mean to remove the column `diary` from the output?

Comment: Hmm, that was odd. The original output I got when I ran your code had the same value for `df_out$output` for everyone. I cleared my environment and ran it again and got what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: Great, @epiguy! I have just added to my previous solution another solution that replaces the nested `for` cycles by a `map_dfr` function of `purrr`.

Answer (score 1):

We can collapse the regex and extract the words ("\w+") that preceed or follow the collapsed pattern. The `regex()` function allows the argument `ignore_case = TRUE`, which is very useful for case-insensitive matching. We may have to include optional word boundaries arount the collapsed pattern, so both `rice` and `price`, `ham` or `hammed` are included.
I made some small changes to the data to make it more illustrative.

I posted two answers.
One will exclude matches inside larger words, such as "hammed" or "price", so non-food matches will return empty strings.
The other is more inclusive.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% mutate(Output = str_extract_all (diary,
                                        regex(paste0("\\w+\\s+(",
                                                     paste("\\b",foods, "\\b", collapse = "|", sep=''),
                                                     ")\\s+\\w+"),
                                              ignore_case=TRUE)))
```

**output 1**

```
  id                        diary             Output
1  1    I ate rice and corn today       ate rice and
2  2             Sue ate my corn.                  
3  3         He just hammed it up                  
4  4      Corny jokes are my fave                  
5  5    What is the price of milk                  
6  6 I like to eat ham sandwiches eat ham sandwiches
```

**solution 2**

```
df %>% mutate(Output = str_extract_all (diary,
                                        regex(paste0("\\w+\\s+(",
                                                     paste("\\b\\w*",foods, "\\w*\\b", collapse = "|", sep=''),
                                                     ")\\s+\\w+"),
                                              ignore_case=TRUE)))

  id                        diary             Output
1  1    I ate rice and corn today       ate rice and
2  2             Sue ate my corn.                  
3  3         He just hammed it up     just hammed it
4  4      Corny jokes are my fave                  
5  5    What is the price of milk       the price of
6  6 I like to eat ham sandwiches eat ham sandwiches
```

**data**

```
foods <- c('corn', 'hot dog', 'ham', 'rice')
df <- data.frame(id = 1:6,
                 diary = c('I ate rice and corn today',
                           'Sue ate my corn.',
                           'He just hammed it up',
                           'Corny jokes are my fave',
                           'What is the price of milk',
                           'I like to eat ham sandwiches'))
```

**FINAL EDIT**

I figured out the problem with "corn", and handled the multiple matches issue.
We have to do a nested loop. First loop through all entries in "diary"(outer loop). Then, in the inner loop, loop through all "foods", and call "str_extract_all", with the appropriate regex. The initial regex required a food word be preceded or followed by another word, so foods at sentence boundaries were not matched. I included a `?` quantifier (0 or 1 matches) around the surrounding words (`\\w+\\s+`) so it all works smoothly. The only issue left is the order of the matches in multiple matches, it is still odd. But I think the solution is fine now.

```
df %>% mutate(output=map(df$diary,
                         ~map(foods, \(x) str_extract_all(.x,
                                                          regex(paste0("(\\w+\\s+)?(",
                                                                       paste("\\b\\w*", x, "\\w*\\b", collapse = "|", sep=''),
                                                                       ")(\\s+\\w+)?"),
                                                                ignore_case=TRUE))))%>%
                      map(unlist))

  id                        diary                       output
1  1    I ate rice and corn today and corn today, ate rice and
2  2             Sue ate my corn.                      my corn
3  3         He just hammed it up               just hammed it
4  4      Corny jokes are my fave                  Corny jokes
5  5    What is the price of milk                 the price of
6  6 I like to eat ham sandwiches           eat ham sandwiches
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! This is close to the solution but not quite. The output from your code yields `rice and`, `my corn`, `ham`, `<NA>`, and `rice of`. Some things I noticed: #1: The search should be case-insensitive and #2: the output includes only 1 key word for observations with 2 key words. I noticed there were two close parentheses missing at the end of your code. Adding them in got the code to work but still didn't address points 1 and 2.

Comment: I improved it. It is still not quite right, as "Corn" is not matching (may be some issue with the word boundary or the literal dot "." at the end).
Please tell me if this helps. I hope you can pick it up from here. This solution is still not returning the second match. For multiple matches, we may have to call the function individually on every element of "foods", in a loop. I may continue working on this tomorrow (it is a bit late here in Brazil)

Comment: Please see my recently updated asnwer.

Comment: Thanks so much for working on this! Your output is just what I'm looking for. Unfortunately, I can't reproduce it. When run as is, I get `Error: unexpected ')' in "                map(unlist))"`. Seems like the `mutate` function is missing a closed parentheses. When I move the second closed parentheses from the second `map` function to before the last `%>%`, I get this error: `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default`. I'm trying to debug it but this is new territory for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure whether that's 100% helpful but worth a try:

First, define your keywords as a case-insensitive alternation pattern:

```
patt <- paste0("(?i)(", paste0(foods, collapse = "|"), ")")
```

Then extract the word on the `left`, the keyword itself called `node`, and the word on the `right` using `stringr`'s function `str_extract_all`:

```
library(stringr)
df1 <- data.frame(
  left = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df$diary), paste0("(?i)(\\S+|^)(?=\\s?", patt, ")"))),
  node = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df$diary), patt)),
  right = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df$diary), paste0("(?<=\\s?", patt, "\\s?)(\\S+|$)")))
  )
```

Result:

```
df1
  left node right
1  ate rice   and
2  and corn today
3   my corn      
4 just  ham   med
5      Corn     y
6    p rice    of
```

While this is not exactly the expected output it may still serve your purpose **iff** that purpose is to check whether a match is indeed a keyword. In lines 5 and 6, for example, the view provided by `df1` immediately makes it clear that these are not keyword matches.

**EDIT**:

This solution preserves the `id`values:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
extract_ <- function(df_row){
  df1 <- data.frame(
    id = df_row$id,    
    left = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df_row$diary), paste0("(?i)(\\S+|^)(?=\\s?", patt, ")"))),
    node = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df_row$diary), patt)),
    right = unlist(str_extract_all(gsub("[.,!?]", "", df_row$diary), paste0("(?<=\\s?", patt, "\\s?)(\\S+|$)")))
  )
}

df %>% 
  group_split(id) %>%    # splits data frame into list of bins, i.e. by id
  map_dfr(.x, .f = ~ extract_(.x))  # now we iterate over bins with our function
  id left node right
1  1  ate rice   and
2  1  and corn today
3  2   my corn      
4  3 just  ham   med
5  4      Corn     y
6  5    p rice    of
```

Comment: This is great! I agree with you about your iff statement. My only comment is that the ID is missing from the output. I will try to tinker with it but will need to learn some new tricks.

Comment: Have added edited solution which preserves the `id`s